# With allow_url_fopen disabled in php, how to get a remote file with progress?

Tags: php, curl, fopen, fsockopen

I have this code that gets a remote url and also shows progress to the user:

```
$fpIn = fopen($remoteUrl, 'r');
if ( !$fpIn ) logdie('FAILED:Remote url cannot be opened for reading');

$fpOut = fopen($localPath, 'w');
if ( !$fpOut ) logdie('FAILED:Local file cannot be opened for writing');

$dlen = 0;
while ( !feof($fpIn) )
{
    $data = fread($fpIn, 4096);
    fwrite($fpOut, $data);

    $dlen += strlen($data);

    logshow("FSIZE:".$dlen);
}

fclose($fpIn);
fclose($fpOut);

logshow("DONE:".$dlen);

...
```

The `logdie()` function simply updates the msg to a db field and die... while the `logshow()` function updates the msg in db and continue to run the code...

From the browser, there is a repeated ajax call that checks the db and informs the user with the status of the process...

Problem occurs on servers where allow_url_fopen is disabled

I can use curl or fsockopen if they are available, but then I cannot get progress of file download which is the main thing why I used fopen.

Is there any workaround to get the remote file saved on server and also at the same time get progress of the process?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/q/28326126/3885509

Comment: This looks promising `curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, 'write_progress' );` I have to check the implementation though, but its a good direction... thanks for that